# How to get Linux command line functions for Windows?

Tags: linux, bash, caffe

I am following Caffe on this [tutorial](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/mnist.html). I am using Windows so I don't have the Linux functions. Is there an easy way I can get Linux functions ? When I run the shell script it launches Bash which immediately closes. It doesn't seem to download anything.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# This scripts downloads the mnist data and unzips it.

DIR="$( cd "$(dirname "$0")" ; pwd -P )"
cd "$DIR"

echo "Downloading..."

for fname in train-images-idx3-ubyte train-labels-idx1-ubyte t10k-images-idx3-ubyte t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte
do
    if [ ! -e $fname ]; then
        echo "done"
        wget --no-check-certificate http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/${fname}.gz
        gunzip ${fname}.gz
        echo "done"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Take a look at https://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: cygwin is the default choice but there are a few alternatives, such as windows 10's bash for windows or mingw. Window's git also comes with a bash console called "git bash", so if it's installed you could get away with installing additional software

Comment: Caffe has [a windows port](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows) mentioned on their web site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider installing such an environment, e.g. start with CYGWIN:
https://www.cygwin.com/